# ValueChangeEvent for h:selectOneMenu in JSF causing Issue?

Tags: jsf, datatable

[image: Project Index Data Table].

I have the Rich Data table which contains the two drop down one for "Status" and other for the "Size" in the rich columns. I have two separate valuechange listener method i.e. statusChangedListener(ValueChangeEvent event) and sizeChangedListener(ValueChangeEvent) which invokes when any of the values are changing from any of those two drop 
down respectively.

Now, what i am facing the issue is... When I change any of the status from the "Status" drop down in the rich datatable column, my statusChangedListener() method is invoked that is correct but after completing execution of that method, the system internally invoked other listener method i.e sizeChangedListener() that is wrong even if I am 
not changing anything from the "Size" drop down. As my size changed listener will invoked when I change anything from the size drop down.

Please find the below code

<rich:datatable>

<rich:column id="statusColumn" filterMethod="#{projectFilterBean.filterProjectTable}"

```
              filterValue="#{projectFilterBean.filterValue}"

              sortBy="#{project.status.description}">



    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Status"/></f:facet>



            <h:selectOneMenu id="test" value="#{project.status}"

                               converter="#{statusConverter}"

                              valueChangeListener="#{projectController.projectStatusChanged}"

                              styleClass="statusSelector" immediate="true">



                <f:selectItems value="#{projectController.existingStatusSelectItems}"/>



                <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="data_table,data_scroller" status="waitStatus" />



            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

</rich:column>

<rich:column id="dimensionColumn"

```
              filterMethod="#{projectFilterBean.filterProjectTableWithSize}"

              filterValue="#{projectFilterBean.filterSizeValue}"

              sortBy="#{project.dimension.widthAndHeight}">



     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Size"/></f:facet>



             <h:selectOneMenu value="#{project.dimension}"

                              converter="#{dimensionConverter}"

                              valueChangeListener="#{projectController.sizeChanged}"

                              styleClass="dimensionSelector">



                <f:selectItems value="#{projectController.existingDimensionSelectItems}"/>



            </h:selectOneMenu>

 </rich:column>
```

..

Java Code

```
 public void sizeChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
     try {
         Project selectedProject = (Project) getProjectDataTable().getRowData();
         Dimension oldDimension = selectedProject.getDimension();
         Dimension selectedDimension = (Dimension) event.getNewValue();

    //     doing some business logic over here

 }
```

}

```
     public void projectStatusChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) 
     {

        try 
        {
         Project selectedProject = (Project) getProjectDataTable().getRowData();
         Status oldStatus = selectedProject.getStatus();
         Status selectedStatus = (Status) event.getNewValue();

         if (selectedStatus != null) {
             selectedProject.setStatus(selectedStatus);
             selectedProject.setUpdatedAt(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

             if (selectedStatus.getName().equals("PROJECT_ACTIVE")) {

                 if (selectedProject.getActivatedAt() == null) {

                     selectedProject.setActivatedAt(new         Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                 }

                 selectedProject.setDeletable(false);
            }

            selectedProject.setXmlUpdate(true);

            if(projectService.updateWithReturn(selectedProject))

                logger.debug(selectedProject + "Status changed from " + oldStatus.getDescription() + " to " +

                selectedStatus.getDescription());

       }

   } catch (Exception ex) {

   logger.error(ex.getMessage());

  }
```

}

Kindly help me to sort out this issue, as we are having this serious issues on our production application.

Please find the attached form contains the rich Datatable.